# Error for predict using svm in R: test data does not match model

Tags: r, debugging, svm

I am trying to do support vector machine regression in R, using e1071 library.

the model is: model = svm(deflated_price~year+month+beds+room_in_apt+nhood, data = train_sample)

The model seems to fit:

```
 summary(model)
```

Call:

```
svm(formula = deflated_price ~ year + month + beds + room_in_apt + nhood, 
      data = train_sample)


Parameters:
   SVM-Type:  eps-regression 
 SVM-Kernel:  radial 
       cost:  1 
      gamma:  0.01149425 
    epsilon:  0.1 

Number of Support Vectors:  48744
```

And I try to do: y_hat = predict(model, newdata = test_sample)

but I get the error: test data does not match model !

Here is the result of do str(train_sample) and str(test_sample)

```
str(train_sample)
'data.frame':   48752 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ year          : Factor w/ 19 levels "2000","2001",..: 5 17 5 17 14 13 16 6 7 17 ...
 $ nhood         : chr  "sea cliff" "hayes valley" "pacific heights" "noe valley" ...
 $ beds          : chr  "2" "1" "3" "1" ...
 $ room_in_apt   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ month         : Factor w/ 12 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 9 2 10 10 12 3 11 1 2 3 ...
 $ deflated_price: num  565 920 3055 616 1399 ...

str(test_sample)
'data.frame':   5000 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ year       : Factor w/ 19 levels "2000","2001",..: 5 5 5 5 5 6 5 6 8 5 ...
 $ nhood      : chr  "alamo square" "alamo square" "alamo square" "alamo square" ...
 $ beds       : chr  "0" "2" "1" "1" ...
 $ room_in_apt: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ month      : Factor w/ 12 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 6 6 11 8 7 1 8 3 9 9 ...
```

The variables seem to match, so what's causing the problem?

I tried adding deflated_price to test_sample, but that didn't work either.

Comment: The levels in the "nhood" variable need to be equivalent between the train and test set.  Are you sure all the category variables values are represented in the training dataset?

Comment: @Dave2e, 47 levels in training sample, 46 levels in testing sample, but this might be it. Thanks.